# Multi row infinite scrolling gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery, infinite

How can I get a multi row infinite loop, scrolling gallery in html/css/javascript?

Comment: Put the images in divs or similar, then scroll them endlessly.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is, when you reach the end of the list (depending on which direction you are scrolling), grab the first element of the list and append it after the currently visualized one, this way you will start from the beginning.

If you are scrolling to the right or to the bottom, you have to grab the element at the beginning of the list and place it at the end of the list.

If you are scrolling to the left or to the top, you have to grab the last element of the list and place it first in the list.

This is a really simple way of achieving an infinite scrolling.